# What is the default list of stopwords used in Lucene's StopFilter?

Tags: java, apache, lucene, information-retrieval, stop-words

Lucene have a default stopfilter (http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopFilter.html), does anyone know which are words in the list?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The [default stop words](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/stopwords.html) set in `StandardAnalyzer` and `EnglishAnalyzer` is from `StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET`, as found in the [source file](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.java#L46):

```
"a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
"for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
"no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
"that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
"they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
```

`StopFilter` itself defines no default set of stop words.

Comment: I'm using `Lucene` 5.5.0 for a keywords fetching. I specify the stop words filter with `tokenStream = new StopFilter(new ClassicFilter(new LowerCaseFilter(stdToken)), StopAnalyzer.ENGLISH_STOP_WORDS_SET);` but `Lucene` doesn't filter stop words. Is there something what I miss?