# How do Lucene search terms work

Tags: .net, lucene, lucene.net

I am using Lucene .net and have created a search that looks like this.

```
{+(Title:it*)}
```

This is pulling back a document with the title "this is an idea - i think its irrelevant "

If I create another search term as

```
{(Title:it*) (Title:s*)}
```

This pulls back "IT support"

Can anyone explain this, I would expect the first search to also pull back "IT Support"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely because "it" is a stopword and is ignored - both when indexing and searching.

You can find the full list of English stopwords [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527741/what-is-the-default-list-of-stopwords-used-in-lucenes-stopfilter).

Comment: That sound right, I added a new doc called "GR Support" and a search of {+(Title:gr*)} returns it. Thanks!