# Cannot search with keyword 'with' in LINQ?

Tags: linq, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore8

Currently I am writing a query by using LINQ for Sitecore search content. Having a strange is that I cannot search content with keyword 'with'. Everyone have idea for this ?

```
using (var searchContext = index.CreateSearchContext())
        {
            var result = searchContext.GetQueryable<SearchResultItem>()
                            .Where(w =>
                                w.Content.Contains(searchText)
                            );
        }
```

The result is empty, I also have try with operator 'like' (w.Content.Lile) but result empty.

Comment: Try this: `...w.Content.Contains(searchText,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Lucene.net / sitecore, but it's possible that "with" is a stopword and Lucene removes it when indexing documents. Try including some other keywords in your query to see if you get results. See [What is the default list of stopwords used in Lucene's StopFilter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527741/what-is-the-default-list-of-stopwords-used-in-lucenes-stopfilter) for more details on stopwords.

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine, the only thing I could see causing an issue would be a case issue. Try this instead:

`x.Content.ToUpper().Contains(searchText.ToUpper())`

Also, not sure about the Lucene.Net implementation, but this looks like simple Linq-SQL or EF to me, and the .Contains() method is executed locally, not remotely.

Comment: Thank you ! Its seem not effective with Lucene.net.