# Lucene.Net fails to search keyword "The"

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am using Lucene.Net (Version Lucene 3.0.3). While searching for keyword "The",
it gives less than 5 results when there is plenty of records matching that keyword.
It works fine for all other keywords.

Does lucene have any problems with 'The' ??? :-)

Comment: Most people don't want to search for [stop words](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527741/what-is-the-default-list-of-stopwords-used-in-lucenes-stopfilter). You can customize this if you do.

Comment: That would likely depend on what analyzers you are using. E.g. there is a good chance you have a [StopFilter](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/core/StopFilter.html) in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in the comments, your problem is the Analyzer you are using.

StandardAnalyzer does various things to do with grammar, but also removes a default set of english stop-words (a, and, or, then etc) "the" is one of these.

You can create it like

```
  var a  new StandardAnalyzer(version, new HashSet<string>());
```

Giving it an empty hashset says "there are no stop words"