# ElasticSearch: List of english stopwords

Tags: elasticsearch

Where can I find the latest list of stopwords in ElasticSearch 6.3 that get used when we choose `_english_` as the language as mentioned in the [Stop Token Filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis-stop-tokenfilter.html) documentation.

Comment: It seems Elastic Search is using Lucene's list of stop words. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17527741/what-is-the-default-list-of-stopwords-used-in-lucenes-stopfilter https://gist.github.com/kimchy/1626305

Answer (score 3):

Elasticsearch is using the Lucene defaults for this. Up until a week ago or so this used to be in https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/branch_7x/lucene/core/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/standard/StandardAnalyzer.java#L47-L53.

Now it has been moved to https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/lucene/analysis/common/src/java/org/apache/lucene/analysis/en/EnglishAnalyzer.java#L44-L50, but the list is the same:

```
final List<String> stopWords = Arrays.asList(
    "a", "an", "and", "are", "as", "at", "be", "but", "by",
    "for", "if", "in", "into", "is", "it",
    "no", "not", "of", "on", "or", "such",
    "that", "the", "their", "then", "there", "these",
    "they", "this", "to", "was", "will", "with"
);
```